# How can I create a SQL Server 2000 table in ASP.NET Bottom click event by using vb?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2000

I am just beginner in ASP.NET programming, I am trying to prepare a small billing project by using ASP.NET and VB.NET.

I would like to create a SQL Server 2000 table by passing table name and number of rows in textbox control.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: you won't get help unless you ask a specific question

Comment: plz mention proper tags... like asp.net ,sql-server,sql

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the sp_executesql stored procedure to archive that type of task. Here is a very simple example in VB.NET

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("your DB connection string goes here")
        cn.Open()

        Dim createSql As String

        createSql = "BEGIN "

        createSql += "EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE table1(id INT)'; "

        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            createSql += "EXECUTE sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ")'; "
        Next

        createSql += "END "

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(createSql, cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

To know more about sq_executesql SP, read this article
[using sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx)

Comment: thanks alot. its working! but i need to add 10 Rows Dynamically after creating this table example                                  ID:                                                                 1                                                                   2                                                                    ....10

Comment: Look at the code again..I've edited it..I think it will work for you.